# Angular ng-disabled with function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I want to use disabled-ng with dynamic value returned from a function.

I have tried several ways but it is not working.

```
<textarea id="{{exercise.type}}" ng-disabled={{prova}}></textarea>
......
<textarea id="{{exercise.type}}" ng-disabled=prova></textarea>
......
<textarea id="{{exercise.type}}" ng-disabled=prova()></textarea>
```

with this javascript function

```
$scope.prova=function(e){               
               return true;
       };
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
ng-disabled="prova()"
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3eqz2/2/

Comment: using a function can cause a $digest iterator overload, when the element is bound to a model that is loaded dynamically

Comment: @GregJF I am having a problem with  $digest iterator overload. How do you work around this?

Comment: function should be fast and simple, return value for example, calculate this value when something changes, for example use get/set function on your model properties to calculate valuefor ng-disabled function. Also angular often can use valueOf or toString, if you are return an object in prova() function

Answer (score 0):

Digest loops happen when the function, changes view model data.  If your function does not change the view model,  it shouldn't cause a digest loop.

ng-if is a good example of something that will cause a digest loop.

This is in response to 'what to do when you have a digest loop.'

Answer:

Don't use function in things that trigger the view model.